# Why arrow function is causing an error where there is 'this' keyword in that function in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I was trying to learn about how to create custom services. As I follow ES6, I used fat arrow.

```
app.service('randNumGenerator', () => {
    let randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
    this.generate = () => randNum;
});
```

When I have used fat arrow for that anonymous fucntion, it's causing a error saying

```
angular_v1.7.9.js:15570 TypeError: Function.prototype.bind.apply(...) is not a constructor
    at Object.instantiate (angular_v1.7.9.js:5158)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular_v1.7.9.js:4994)
    at Object.invoke (angular_v1.7.9.js:5143)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular_v1.7.9.js:4978)
    at Object.invoke (angular_v1.7.9.js:5143)
    at angular_v1.7.9.js:4932
    at getService (angular_v1.7.9.js:5086)
    at injectionArgs (angular_v1.7.9.js:5111)
    at Object.invoke (angular_v1.7.9.js:5135)
    at $controllerInit (angular_v1.7.9.js:11707)
(anonymous) @ angular_v1.7.9.js:15570
```

Instated of using first is used this by only removing the arrow function

```
app.service('randNumGenerator', function() {
    let randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
    this.generate = () => randNum;
});
```

But when I removed the fat arrow, it worked fine.
What is the actual reason behind this?

Comment: Do a console.log(this) for both cases and you will find out

Answer (score 0):

Fat arrow functions can't always be a substitute for the old-styled `function`-keyword functions.

The normal functions have their own context, it means that if they're called with `new` then `this` points to the object itself, while if they're invoked without `new` it points to the global object.

Fat arrow functions, instead, can't be used as constructors, `this` always points to the outer context, and they don't have the `Function` prototype. It means that `bind`, `call` and `apply` can't be called on them.

In your case, if you receive that error, it means that `app.service` internally calls `bind`.